# How to convert PDF to Grayscale

Tags: windows, linux, pdf

I scanned a document in color to PDF, and I don't want to re-scan it.

How can I convert this PDF document to grayscale (preferably without loss of other information)?

My usual toolset of [doPDF](http://www.dopdf.com/), [pdfsam](http://www.pdfsam.org/) and the [Neevia online converter](http://convert.neevia.com/pdfconvert/) don't work here. I was thinking I could simply print to PDF and select the Grayscale color option, but [doPDF](http://www.dopdf.com/) doesn't have that option.

I'm using Windows, but I can probably handle a solution for any OS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a solution [in a blog post](http://vince-debian.blogspot.com/2008/05/pdf-conversion-to-grayscale.html):

With GhostScript (and Windows users can access `gs` via [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)), you can do it with the following command:

```
gs \
  -o grayscale.pdf \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
  -sColorConversionStrategy=Gray \
  -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceGray \
  -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 \
   source.pdf
```

This will convert `source.pdf` to `grayscale.pdf` and not put you into a GhostScript shell (due to the `-o` option instead of the `-sOutputFile=` option).

Comment: OMG!, what a complicated workaround for avoiding the Ghostscript command prompt to stay up after the processing! A more simple solution is to add `-dNOPAUSE -dBATCH` to the commandline. The `-dNOPAUSE` part spares you from hitting *[return]* after each page, and the `-dBATCH` part saves you from typing *'quit'* at to exit the `GS>` prompt. And even shorter: just use `-o grayscale.pdf` for specifying the output file; this `-o ...` implicitly also sets `-dBATCH -dNOPAUSE`...

Comment: It appears this no longer works with recent versions of Ghostscript: http://ghostscript.com/pipermail/gs-bugs/2012-May/025904.html says "'Gray' is not a documented legal value for ColorConversionStrategy"

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a job for Imagemagick. Windows and Linux versions are available.

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

This should do the trick at the command line:

```
convert -colorspace GRAY original.pdf grayscale.pdf
```

Comment: @nodiscc: you should be aware that ImageMagick employs *Ghostscript* as its *delegate* to render and interpret the PDF input file... (So without a working Ghostscript installation on the same system it won't work.)

Answer (score 1):

Just install [PDFCreator](http://filehippo.com/download_pdfcreator/). It has a small footprint and adds a PDF printer to Windows. And as you've mentioned, just select grayscale when printing to it.

Comment: Not that this would make your answer invalid, but do PDF prints lose information on each print?

Comment: I believe not, but you could just try - it's free :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `mutool` (version ≥ 1.22.1) to change the colorspace of PDF files.

```bash
mutool recolor -c gray -o "gray.pdf" "color.pdf"
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76245363/11407924).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the free service at http://greyscalepdf.com to convert any PDF to greyscale.

Comment: Nice; good find! Some people have sensitive information in their PDFs and don't want to use an online conversion service, though.

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

[Sejda.com](https://www.sejda.com) has an online tool for [**Converting PDF docs to Grayscale**](https://www.sejda.com/grayscale-pdf).

1. Go to https://www.sejda.com/grayscale-pdf and upload your doc
2. Click **Convert PDF to Grayscale** and then **Download** to save your grayscaled document.

[image: Grayscale PDF converter and it's options]

The online grayscale converter is free to use 3 times per hour, for files up to 50Mb or 200 pages.

There's also an offline version of the same tool that you can install and work locally, without uploading your files: https://www.sejda.com/desktop

Disclaimer: I'm one of the developers.

Answer (score 0):

Tried several Ghostcript and Imagemagick commands mentioned and all ended with an error and no output file. The only one that gave me a file was this that I found on Imagemagick website:

```
convert in.pdf -grayscale Rec709Luminance out.pdf
```

The image quality was reduced though.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Sejda.com online tool mentioned in another response, there is another online tool where you can [convert a pdf to greyscale:](https://supertool.org/convert-color-pdfs-to-black-and-white/)

- https://supertool.org/convert-color-pdfs-to-black-and-white/

That site has features for making PDFs pure black and white or greyscale. You can also make other image adjustments (like brightness).

[image]